# Creating a download link in Spring-MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, download

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. In the application, I am using a method to create a pdf file from the screenshot, taken by using some functions in frontend. Now, there is a button which the user clicks, and it sends the image via 'POST', and then it is transformed to a PDF. The problem is, because this is a 'POST', I am unable to use the normal file download methods to return the file.

After some research I found out, jquery can be used to download the files, but it needs the download URL for the same. I am posting my code for creating the screenshot, PDF, kindly let me know how to create the download URL.

Controller  class :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/canvas/screenshot", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String saveCanvasScreenshot(@RequestBody String body, Model model,HttpServletResponse response) {
 Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        body = body.substring(30);
        String path = "/home/akshay/"+person.getFirstName()+".pdf";
        try {
            body = URLDecoder.decode(body, "UTF-8");
            canvasImageBytes = body.getBytes();
            canvasImageBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(canvasImageBytes);
            Canvas canvas = canvasService.getCanvasById(staticcanvasid);
            canvas.setCanvasimage(canvasImageBytes);
            canvasService.addCanvas(canvas, person);
            boolean b = convertimagetopdf(body);
            if(b == true){
               // And here I would like to sent the URL back as a String.
}
```

Javascript method :

```
 $("#pdf-creator").click(function(){
           document.styleSheets[4].disabled=true;
           var screenshot = $('#main').clone();
           renderingScreenshot = true;
           setWidthsForScreenshot(screenshot);
           html2canvas($('#main'), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    img = encodeURIComponent(String(img));
                   $.ajax({
                        url: baseURL + '/canvas/screenshot',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: img,
                        success: function(){
                            document.styleSheets[4].disabled=false;
                            $('#loading-image').show();

                        },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                                $('body').append(xhr.responseText);
                                document.styleSheets[4].disabled=false;
                                $('#loading-image').show();

                            }
                    });
                }
                });
       });
       initializeGridstack();
```

Comment: _kindly let me know how to create the download URL_ - Kindly let us know how you save the pdf in order to be consumed later on.

Comment: The pdf is saved on the disk...the path of file is in 'path' variable.

Comment: And where's the problem? You seem to know how "to use the normal file download methods to return the file". So I'm sure you have another controller method that returns the saved pdf.

Comment: @zeroflagL  The link on system and the download URL are different things. I want to give create a download URL for that file which the user can use for downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can return download link in response, and then make GET request. In Spring you can do this to obtain file from downloadble link.

```
@RequestMapping("/models/{fileId}.smth")
            @ResponseBody
            public HttpEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String fileId) throws IOException {
                byte[] model = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File( "C:/folder/" + fileId + ".smth"));
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                headers.setContentLength(model.length);
                return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(model, headers);
            }
```